# How to make a python program that lists the positions and displays and error message if not found

Tags: python

I did this code:

```
sentence = input("Type in your sentance ").lower().split()
Word = input("What word would you like to find? ")
Keyword = Word.lower().split().append(Word)
positions = []

for (S, subword) in enumerate(sentence):
    if (subword == Word):
        positions.append
        print("The word" , Word , "is in position" , S+1)
```

But there are 2 problems with it; I dont know how to write a code when the users word is not found and to but the positions in "The word position is in [1,3,6,9].
Any help?
Thanks

Comment: What is this line `Keyword = Word.lower().split().append(Word)` and this line `positions.append` supposed to do?

Comment: the line Keyword = Word.lower().split().append(Word) should make what ever is in 'Word' a low case and split the words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is having multiple errors. I am pasting here the sample code for your reference:

```
from collections import defaultdict

sentence_string = raw_input('Enter Sentence: ')
# Enter Sentence: Here is the content I need to check for index of all words as Yes Hello Yes Yes Hello Yes

word_string = raw_input("Enter Words: ")
# Enter Words: yes hello

word_list = sentence_string.lower().split()
words = word_string.lower().split()

my_dict = defaultdict(list)
for i, word in enumerate(word_list):
     my_dict[word].append(i)

for word in words:
    print "The word" , word, "is in position " , my_dict[word]

# The word yes is in position  [21, 23, 24, 26]
# The word hello is in position  [22, 25]
```

The approach here is:

1. Break your sentence i.e `sentence_string` here into list of words
2. Break your word string into list of words.
3. Create a dictionary `my_dict` to store all the indexes of the words in `word_list`
4. Iterate over the `words` to get your result with index, based on the value you store in `my_dict`.

*Note:* The commented part in above example is basically the output of the code.

Answer (score 0):

> Use index.

```
a = 'Some sentence of multiple words'
b = 'a word'


def list_matched_indices(list_of_words, word):
    pos = 0
    indices = []
    while True:
        try:
            pos = list_of_words.index(word, pos)
            indices.append(pos)
            pos+=1
        except:
            break
    if len(indices):
        print(indices)
        return indices
    else:
        print ("Not found")

list_matched_indices(a, b)
```

Comment: @anonymous-user Did this help?